# Find text after some occurrence

Tags: python

I have a file with some key-words, written in uppercase. After the uppercase-text, there can be more text, but there is every time a part which begins with "Test:".
I should get this text beginning after "Test:" until there are two newlines (\n\n).

Example:

```
ESC
Here can be something.
Test: Here is the definition.

Here can also be some text.

TAB
Here can be something.
Test: Here is the definition.
There can be some more lines. 

Here can also be some text.
```

So, if I search "TAB", I'd like to print out "Here is the definition.\There can be some more lines." How can I do this?

Thanks for any help! :)

Edit:
At the moment, I search the line which equals "TAB". I.e. I have the line number, but how to continue?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Please read up on [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import sys

```
s="""ESC
Here can be something.
Defn: Here is the definition.

Here can also be some text.

TAB
Here can be something.
Defn: Here is the definition.
There can be some more lines.

Here can also be some text."""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # search =  sys.argv[1]
    search = 'TAB' #Sample search
    index = s.find(search) # Find the index of search term
    def_index = s.find('Defn', index) # Find the index of 'Defn' 
    end_index =  s.find('\n\n', def_index) # Find the end of definition 
    print index , def_index, end_index
    print s[def_index: end_index][5:]  # 5 is len('Defn:')
```

[link]https://gist.github.com/anonymous/646f5ba66587656a2c12